# Does reading Chinese sentences improve my speaking?

Tags: learning, spoken, reading

If I do not have anyone to practice speaking with, will reading Mandarin help me speak Mandarin?

Answer (score 3):

I’m Chinese and currently studying English.  If you're just reading, your progress is probably very slow.

I think that the best way to improve your skill is to have conversation with people.

> 你好，朋友，我是中国人，我正在学习英文。
>   如果你只是阅读，可能你的进展很慢。
>   我觉得提升你能力的最好办法是跟别人交流。

Answer (score 0):

It should help! Reading generally helps to improve your grasp of grammar and vocabulary. If the sentences are from real life speaking situations, then that also will help.

reading can be one of a number of complementary ways of studying the language. The website [hacking Chinese](https://www.hackingchinese.com) has lots of useful resources on optimising your study techniques. Here's a link to a group of resources related to reading: [link](https://www.hackingchinese.com/archive-2/reading/); and here's the link for the resources on speaking: [link](https://www.hackingchinese.com/archive-2/speaking/).